# Dividing by Trig Functions

Tags: trigonometry

I'm sorry if this is very simple, but I am a little confused.

I have an equation which is $-2\times \cos(2x) \times f(x)=0$. Am I able to simple divide both sides by $-2\times \cos(2x)$?

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but $f(x) = y - a_0 - a_2\cos(2x) - b_2\sin(2x) - a_4\cos(4x) - b_4\sin(4x)$

Comment: Doing so would eliminate all the solutions $x$ for which $\cos(2x)=0$ (assuming no common solutions among that and $f(x)=0$)

Comment: "*I have an equation which is $a\cdot b = 0$.  Am I able to simply divide both sides by $a$?*"  Not if $a$ is able to be zero, no.  Same here.  The correct conclusion from $ab=0$ is that $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: You have a product that's equal to zero which means one of the factors is zero. If you just divide by one factor, you may lose some solutions.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I am sorry to bother you again, but what if for example, b = (c+d)? Would that not result in ac = -ad which could then be simplified to c=-d?

Comment: It would result in $ac=-ad$ but that does **not** get simplified to $c=-d$.  Consider what happens if $a=0, c=5, d=2873297839782234789$.  We would indeed have that $0\cdot (5+2873297839782234789)=0$ and that $0\cdot 5 = -0\cdot 2873297839782234789$ but this does **not** mean that $5$ is equal to $-2873297839782234789$.  You could only simplify it to $c=-d$ if you know ahead of time that $a$ is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't just divide by something that *might* be $0$. So you need to turn your one equation into two equations: one holds when the term you are trying to divide by is $0$, and one when it doesn't, so you can safely divide by it.

So your one equation $$−2×\cos(2x)×f(x)=0$$ is equivalent to two equations: $$-2×\cos(2x)=0$$ or $$f(x)=0$$ because either you can't divide by $−2×\cos(2x)$ because it's $0$, or you can, so $f(x)$ is $0$.

Of course dividing by $-2$ is fine, because $-2$ isn't $0$, so now you know your solutions for $x$ are firstly the set of solutions for $$\cos(2x)=0$$ unioned with the set of solutions for $$f(x)=0$$

There's a whole genre of 'schoolboy proofs' of $1=2$ that rely on subtly dividing both sides of an equation by zero then conveniently forgetting you've done so, so don't do this!

Comment: So I would have cos(2x) = 0 and y−a0−a2cos(2x)−b2sin(2x)−a4cos(4x)−b4sin(4x)=0?

Comment: You would have $\cos(2x)=0$ **OR** that expression equals zero.  "OR" is a very different word than "AND".

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much for all the help!